# PHP or MySQL removes white spaces

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add an article to my table but when I do and I have an article like this:

```
*this is an article example

This is an article example*
```

It removes the empty line between the two sentences. How can I keep those empty lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that \n is different when you echo it.
So put this before saving

```
 $line = str_replace("\n","<br>",$line);
```

and change $line to whatever your code is.

Comment: Before i echo it out or before i store it in my table?

Comment: Whicheever comes first

Comment: No, it's a bad idea to modify contents if you don't need it. It's better to use the nl2br() function to echo the text: **echo nl2br($article);**

Answer (score 0):

Keep saving contents as you're doing right now, but use "new line to br" function to show the article:

```
<?php
echo nl2br($article);
```

This way, you add the **br** tag only to show contents in page, without modifying your original text.